# row.getList java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to scala.collection.Seq

Tags: scala, apache-spark, row, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to retrieve a list from a row with the following schema element.

```
[info]  |-- ARRAY_FIELD: array (nullable = false)
[info]  |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
```

When printing using

```
row.getAs[WrappedArray[String]]("ARRAY_FIELD")
```

I get the following result

```
WrappedArray(Some String value)
```

But when I attempt to print the data at that index as a list
using....

```
row.getList(0)
```

I get the following exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to scala.collection.Seq
```

Does anyone have any ideas on why this happens and how it can be resolved?

Comment: Can you add the print Schema

Comment: The first code block has the results of the printSchema

Comment: Your Schema does not contain any column of type `BigDecimal` Please check again

Comment: Akash I believe your question actually helped with my question.  I didn't want to post the entire schema because I thought it wasn't necessary but because of your question, I now see that I'm pulling from the wrong index in the schema.  And when I pull from the correct index, everything is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually pulling from the wrong index in the schema.  I assumed that the index for getList was based on the index of the elements shown when using df.printSchema.  But I was wrong.  Off by 6 postions.